# Give "Read More" precedence over excerpt() word count

Tags: filters, excerpt, read-more

By default, `the_excerpt()` displays the content before the `<!--more-->`, trimming it at ~50 words.

Is there any way to prevent this trimming functionality when the `<!--more-->` is present, but still have it work when `<!--more-->` is absent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the hacky way I figured it out:

```
if ( preg_match( '/<!--more-->/', $post->post_content ) ) {
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content( '' ) );
    echo ( $content );
} else {
    the_excerpt();
}
```

(Note that I have a separate "Read More" link after this snippet; if you're wanting to use The Content's default Read More link, remove the space from `get_the_content();`.